# Animating my character in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, ios7, sprite-kit

How can I animate something that is moving across the screen in sprite kit? This is what I have at the moment:

```
-(void)createMan {

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(120, 298);// those coordinates are the bottom left corner

SKSpriteNode *man = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"man1"];
man.position = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
man.zPosition = 6;
[man setScale:0.5f];
[self addChild:man];

// we now want to call this method again repeatedly at a random interval :)

float randomNum = arc4random_uniform(3)+3;
[self performSelector:@selector(createMan) withObject:nil afterDelay:randomNum];

//man moves right
SKAction *moveNodeUp = [SKAction moveByX:400.0 y:0 duration:5];
[man runAction: moveNodeUp];
}
```

So how can I change the picture after a set time is basically what im asking. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I change the picture after a set time is basically what im asking.

[Changing a Sprite's Texture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW47) in the Sprite Kit Programming Guide demonstrates how to use `-animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:` to loop over a sequence of textures over time, which is what you probably want in order to animate your sprite as it moves.

Following the example in that section, you should create an action that uses a sequence of textures. Let's say that you have three textures, `texture1`, `texture2`, and `texture3`. Then you'd put the textures in an array and create an animation action like this:

```
NSArray *walkingUpTextures = @[texture1, texture2, texture3];
SKAction *animateAction = [SKAction animateWithTextures:walkingUpTextures timePerFrame:0.1];
```

Note: you can create the texture array any way you want. I used Objective-C's object literal syntax above, but you can call `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` or any other method that works for you.

To make sure that the animation happens with the movement, and only with the movement, combine that action with your movement action:

```
SKAction *animateAction = [SKAction animateWithTextures:manMovementTextures timePerFrame:0.1];
SKAction *moveNodeUpAction = [SKAction moveByX:400.0 y:0 duration:5];
SKAction *groupAction = [SKAction group:@[animateAction, moveNodeUpAction]];
[man runAction:groupAction];
```

Comment: so in the example on the apple site it says :    animateWithTextures:monsterWalkTextures                                     what should i put if i have 5 images in my project?

Comment: Look at [the docs for that method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_7) (which happens to be the very first method listed for `SKAction` and you'll see that the *textures* parameter is an array of textures. So put your five textures in an array, and pass that array as the first parameter of the method.

Comment: ok but i still don't understand. where you have put manMovementTextures  what should i put?

Comment: Put an array of your textures. I'll modify the example above to illustrate.

Comment: ok but i get an error that says i haven't declared the textures how do i do that

Comment: It sounds like this might be a good time to take a step back and make sure that you understand what's going on rather than trying to cobble bits of example code together. You need to load your textures, either from images or from a texture atlas. But most of all, you really need to read the Sprite Kit Programming Guide that I linked to above -- it explains most of what you need to know pretty clearly.

Comment: k sorry for being a noob  if i put this                               SKTexture *texture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImage:man1];

Comment: No sweat -- it's just that it's easy to fall into the trap of trying to put together different bits and pieces without understanding the bigger picture. And yes, creating a texture like that should work fine if `man1` is a valid `UIImage *`.